# Using wp_remote_post() to post multipart form data with image to iNaturalist REST API

Tags: php, json, wordpress, rest, multipartform-data

I'm developing a WordPress website that allows users to submit observations that are then pushed to the iNaturalist API. I have successfully authenticated, pushed the observation data, and received the ID of the observation from the API. I am completely hung up on pushing a photo with the [POST /observation_photos](https://www.inaturalist.org/pages/api+reference#post-observation_photos) endpoint. My suspicion is that I'm not formatting the payload correctly, but I can't find any working examples of this type of request in a language I'm familiar with, so there's a lot of blind stabbing in the dark.

I've tried a lot of things before posting here so bear with me as I go through them and the results of each.

First, I tried the following:

```
$photo_payload = [
    'method' => 'POST',
    'timeout' => 10,
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => "Bearer $auth",
        'Content-Type' => "multipart/form-data;"
    ],
    'body' => [
        'observation_photo' => [
            'observation_id' => $inat_id
        ],
        'file' =>file_get_contents($photo_sized)
    ]
];
$post_photo = wp_remote_post($inat_base_url . '/observation_photos', $photo_payload);
```

Which results in: `500 Internal Server Error`

Then I tried removing the file from the body array and just send:

```
$photo_payload = [
    'method' => 'POST',
    'timeout' => 10,
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => "Bearer $auth",
        'Content-Type' => "multipart/form-data;"
    ],
    'body' => [
        'observation_photo' => [
            'observation_id' => $inat_id
        ],
        'file' => ''
    ]
];
```

We get a success and iNaturalist adds a placeholder "Processing..." image to the observation (as seen here: https://www.inaturalist.org/observations/8014211).

So that tells me that the file data is not being sent properly. I tried base64_encoding the image data but got a 500 error for that too.

Next up was this attempt:

```
$photo_payload = [
    'method' => 'POST',
    'timeout' => 10,
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => "Bearer $auth",
        'Content-Type' => "multipart/form-data;"
    ],
    'body' => [
        'observation_photo' => [
            'observation_id' => $inat_id
        ],
        'file' => '@' . $photo_sized . ';filename=' . basename($photo_sized) . ';type=' . get_post_mime_type($photo_id)
    ]
];
```

That gave me another `500 Internal Server Error`.

Then I started down the multipart/form-data rabbit hole and based on this post (http://codechutney.com/posting-file-using-wp_remote_post/) tried:

```
$boundary = wp_generate_password( 24 );

$body = '';
$body .= '--' . $boundary . "\r\n";
$body .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="' . basename($photo_sized) . "\"\r\n";
$body .= 'Content-Type: ' . $photo_type . "\r\n\r\n";
$body .= base64_encode(file_get_contents($photo_sized)) . "\r\n";
$body .= '--' . $boundary . "\r\n";
$body .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="observation_photo"' . "\r\n";
$body .= 'Content-Type: application/json' . "\r\n\r\n";
$body .= json_encode(['observation_id' => $inat_id]) . "\r\n";
$body .= '--' . $boundary . '--' . "\r\n";

$photo_payload = [
    'method' => 'POST',
    'timeout' => 10,
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => "Bearer $auth",
        'Content-Type' => "multipart/form-data; boundary=$boundary"
    ],
    'body' => $body
];
```

Alas, another `500 Internal Server Error`.

Seriously, I have been banging my head against the wall on this for so long that I can't remember all the things I tried. At some point, I know I was getting timeout errors too, but I can't recreate them right now.

Other notes: It doesn't seem to change anything if I change the endpoint from observation_photos to observation_photos.json. The file that I am trying to send is 7585 bytes.

Comment: your boundary is generated after you need it

Comment: Whoops, that's because I added it in the wrong place in this question. It's correct in my code. Thanks @rak007 I'll edit the question.

Comment: I submitted a bug to the iNaturalist github: https://github.com/inaturalist/inaturalist/issues/1483 and will keep this question updated

Answer (score 2):

Heard back from a developer at iNaturalist! They let me know the proper formatting of the multipart request is as follows:

```
[body] => --abc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="20170816_071116-150x150.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

[raw image data]
--abc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="observation_photo[observation_id]"

8014211
--abc--
```

So I changed the body of the payload to the following and it works!

```
$body = '';
$body .= '--' . $boundary . "\r\n";
$body .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="' . basename($photo_sized) . "\"\r\n";
$body .= 'Content-Type: ' . $photo_type . "\r\n\r\n";
$body .= base64_encode(file_get_contents($photo_sized)) . "\r\n";
$body .= '--' . $boundary . "\r\n";
$body .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="observation_photo[observation_id]"' . "\r\n";
$body .= 'Content-Type: application/json' . "\r\n\r\n";
$body .= $inat_id . "\r\n";
$body .= '--' . $boundary . '--' . "\r\n";
```

Here's a link to the solution on GitHub issues:
https://github.com/inaturalist/inaturalist/issues/1483#issuecomment-331239325

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot! There is one thing I noticed: You use an escaped double quote to close the filename attribute. This does not work everywhere (in my case). You should only put \r\n in double quotes and everything else in single quotes to prevent it from being escaped.